# Bootstrap <input> not occupying 100% space

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I copied below code form [bootstrap site](http://getbootstrap.com/components/).

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

The `<input>` html tag is not occupying all the 6 columns.  I am using twitter bootstrap 3.3.4 and trying to implement this in my MVC4 application.

Has anyone came across such problem?

Comment: check Site.css that is created by visual studio. There may be css code and it overrides the bootstrap css

Comment: Thanks @AliRızaAdıyahşi  Your guess was right.  There is style in site.css which sets max-width to 280 px.  Thanks for quick response.

Answer (score -2):

just Open Your MVC Project,

Goto Content > Site.css

```
   input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

When You Create MVC Application, It By Default Set the input controls size

Do It, And Try Again.